# Weighted network between cluster centroids - Python

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

The following plots vectors derived from two sets of data points. I also measure and plot the centroid of these points using k-means clustering.

I'm hoping to measure some form of adjacency matrix to plot the network between each cluster based on the number of vectors, which also accounts for the amount of vectors between each cluster. So displaying the weight.

I was thinking the diagonal values of the adjacency matrix could indicate the number of vectors in the same cluster, while the non-diagonal values could indicate the number of vectors between different clusters, while considering the direction?

I'm hoping to produce an output to the one below. Where the nodes are the centroid of the cluster. The diameter of the node should indicate the number of vectors in the same cluster and the line thickness is the number of vectors between the two clusters.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,6))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-80,80,size=(500, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

A = df['A']
B = df['B']

C = df['C']
D = df['D']

Y_sklearn = df[['A','B','C','D']].values

ax.quiver(A, B, (C-A), (D-B), angles = 'xy', scale_units = 'xy', scale = 1, alpha = 0.5) 

model = KMeans(n_clusters = 20)
model.fit(Y_sklearn)

model.cluster_centers_ 
cluster_centers = model.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(cluster_centers[:, 0], cluster_centers[:, 1], 
            color = 'black', s = 100, 
            alpha = 0.7, zorder = 2)

plt.scatter(Y_sklearn[:,0], Y_sklearn[:,1], color = 'blue', alpha = 0.2); 
plt.scatter(Y_sklearn[:,2], Y_sklearn[:,3], color = 'red', alpha = 0.2);
```

Edit 2:

If if fix the data to get the intended network below, the following plots a total of 12 vectors. Two groups of 5 are overlapping, while two are unique.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4],                        
    'B' : [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2],              
    'C' : [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7],   
    'D' : [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7],                                    
    })

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

A = df['A']
B = df['B']

C = df['C']
D = df['D']

ax.quiver(A, B, (C-A), (D-B), angles = 'xy', scale_units = 'xy', scale = 1, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

If I just plot the scatter with cluster centroids, it should look like the following:

```
Y_sklearn = df[['A','B','C','D']].values

model = KMeans(n_clusters = 4)
model.fit(Y_sklearn)

model.cluster_centers_ 
cluster_centers = model.cluster_centers_

plt.scatter(cluster_centers[:, 0], cluster_centers[:, 1], 
        color = 'black', s = 100, 
        alpha = 0.7, zorder = 2)

plt.scatter(cluster_centers[:, 2], cluster_centers[:, 3], 
        color = 'black', s = 100, 
        alpha = 0.7, zorder = 2)
```

[image]

This all works fine. The next step is where I'm having trouble. If I plot the network manually, it should look something like this. The thicker lines display 5 vectors between centroids, while the thinner lines display 1 vector.

[image]

The updated code produces the following network. The `5,5 - 7,7` line is correct, but I'm not getting the other lines that should replicate something similar to the network above.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

def kmeans(arr,num_clusters):

    model = KMeans(n_clusters = num_clusters)
    model.fit(arr)
    model.cluster_centers_ 
    cluster_centers = model.cluster_centers_
    all_labels = model.labels_
    mem_count = Counter(all_labels)

    return cluster_centers,all_labels,mem_count

nclusters_1,nclusters_2 = 2,2
points= df[['A','B','C','D']].values
cluster_one = kmeans(points[:,:2],nclusters_1)
cluster_two = kmeans(points[:,2:],nclusters_2)

# find connections between clusters 
all_combs = [[n1,n2] for n1 in range(nclusters_1) for n2 in range(nclusters_2)]
num_connections = {}
for item in all_combs:
    l1,l2 = cluster_one[1],cluster_two[1]
    mask1 = np.where(l1==item[0])[0]
    mask2 = np.where(l2==item[1])[0]
    num_common = len(list(set(mask1).intersection(mask2)))
    num_connections[(item[0],item[1]+nclusters_1)] = num_common

G = nx.Graph()
node_sizes = {}
node_colors = {}
for k,v in num_connections.items():
    # the number of points in the two clusters 
    s1,s2 = cluster_one[2][k[0]],cluster_two[2][k[1]-nclusters_1]
    G.add_node(k[0],pos=points[:,:2][k[0]])
    G.add_node(k[1],pos=points[:,2:][k[1]])
    G.add_edge(k[0],k[1],color='k',weight=v/3)
    node_sizes[k[0]] = s1;node_sizes[k[1]] = s2
    node_colors[k[0]] = 'k';node_colors[k[1]] = 'k'

edges = G.edges()
d = dict(G.degree)
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
nx.draw(G,pos,edges=edges,
        node_color=[node_colors[v] for v in d.keys()],
        nodelist=d.keys(),
        width=weights,
        node_size=[node_sizes[v]*20 for v in d.keys()])
```

[image]

Comment: add an extra line `pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')` resolves the issue, check out my updated post

Comment: Apologies for the changes. I may need to ask a separate question. Feel like we've made some progress.

Comment: It's ok :) I just noticed a bug in my original post, the node positions should be `G.add_node(k[0],pos=cluster_one[0][k[0]])
    G.add_node(k[1],pos=cluster_two[0][k[1]-nclusters_1])`

Comment: Brilliant! This is it. thanks a lot. Just so I'm clear  `G.add_edge(k[0],k[1],color='k',weight=v/1)` adjusts the weight of the line and `node_size=[node_sizes[v]*10 for v in d.keys()])` is the weight of the node?

Comment: You're welcome my friend :) Exactly, `weight` in `add_edge` controls the edge widths, and `node_sizes` controls the sizes of the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before solving the problem, I guess the `KMeans` clustering should be performed for the first two columns of the `df` and the other two columns separately. If you apply `KMeans` clustering directly to the entire `df`, the connections between two clusters `(A,B)` and `(C,D)` will be trivial.

If it is possible to use `networkx` in your project, here is how you can achieve what you are looking for. First, prepare the data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


def kmeans(arr,num_clusters):
    
    model = KMeans(n_clusters = num_clusters)
    model.fit(arr)
    model.cluster_centers_ 
    cluster_centers = model.cluster_centers_
    all_labels = model.labels_
    mem_count = Counter(all_labels)
    
    return cluster_centers,all_labels,mem_count
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-80,80,size=(200, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
# tail 
A,B = df['A'],df['B']
# end 
C,D = df['C'],df['D']

nclusters_1,nclusters_2 = 20,20
points= df[['A','B','C','D']].values
cluster_one = kmeans(points[:,:2],nclusters_1)
cluster_two = kmeans(points[:,2:],nclusters_2)

# find connections between clusters 
all_combs = [[n1,n2] for n1 in range(nclusters_1) for n2 in range(nclusters_2)]
num_connections = {}
for item in all_combs:
    l1,l2 = cluster_one[1],cluster_two[1]
    mask1 = np.where(l1==item[0])[0]
    mask2 = np.where(l2==item[1])[0]
    num_common = len(list(set(mask1).intersection(mask2)))
    num_connections[(item[0],item[1]+nclusters_1)] = num_common
```

As you can see in the above code, I performed `KMeans` clustering to `(A,B)` and `(C,D)` separately, and you can use different number of clusters for the two sets of points by using different `nclusters_1` and `nclusters_2`. After the data is prepared, we can now visualize it using `networkx`

```
# plot the graph 
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
node_sizes = {}
node_colors = {}
for k,v in num_connections.items():
    # the number of points in the two clusters 
    s1,s2 = cluster_one[2][k[0]],cluster_two[2][k[1]-nclusters_1]
    G.add_node(k[0],pos=cluster_one[0][k[0]])
    G.add_node(k[1],pos=cluster_two[0][k[1]-nclusters_1])
    G.add_edge(k[0],k[1],color='k',weight=v/3)
    node_sizes[k[0]] = s1;node_sizes[k[1]] = s2
    node_colors[k[0]] = 'navy';node_colors[k[1]] = 'darkviolet'
    
edges = G.edges()
d = dict(G.degree)
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
nx.draw(G,pos,edges=edges,
        node_color=[node_colors[v] for v in d.keys()],
        nodelist=d.keys(),
        width=weights,
        node_size=[node_sizes[v]*20 for v in d.keys()])
```

The output figure looks like

[image: output]

In this figure, the actual positions of the points are used for plotting, `(A,B)` are colored `navy` and `(C,D)` are colored `violet`. If you want to scale up the node size, just use a different number than `20` for this line

```
node_size=[node_sizes[v]*20 for v in d.keys()]
```

In order to adjust the width of the edges, use can use a different number other than `3` in this line

```
G.add_edge(k[0],k[1],color='k',weight=v/3)
```

---

**UPDATE**

In the script above, the keys of `num_connections` represent two graph nodes, and the corresponding values represent the number of connections. In order to extract adjacency matrix from `num_connections`, you can try

```
adj_mat = np.zeros((nclusters_1,nclusters_2))
for k,v in num_connections.items():
    entry = (k[0],k[1]-nclusters_1)
    adj_mat[entry] = v
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

To resolve the issue in OP's updated post,

1. add this `pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')` to fix the node positions
2. change `G.add_node(k[0],pos=points[:,:2][k[0]])` and `G.add_node(k[1],pos=points[:,2:][k[1]])` to `G.add_node(k[0],pos=cluster_one[0][k[0]])` and `G.add_node(k[1],pos=cluster_two[0][k[1]-nclusters_1])`

with these two modifications,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4],                        
    'B' : [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2],              
    'C' : [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7],   
    'D' : [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7],                                    
    })

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

A = df['A']
B = df['B']

C = df['C']
D = df['D']

def kmeans(arr,num_clusters):

    model = KMeans(n_clusters = num_clusters)
    model.fit(arr)
    model.cluster_centers_ 
    cluster_centers = model.cluster_centers_
    all_labels = model.labels_
    mem_count = Counter(all_labels)

    return cluster_centers,all_labels,mem_count

nclusters_1,nclusters_2 = 2,2
points= df[['A','B','C','D']].values
cluster_one = kmeans(points[:,:2],nclusters_1)
cluster_two = kmeans(points[:,2:],nclusters_2)

# find connections between clusters 
all_combs = [[n1,n2] for n1 in range(nclusters_1) for n2 in range(nclusters_2)]
num_connections = {}
for item in all_combs:
    l1,l2 = cluster_one[1],cluster_two[1]
    mask1 = np.where(l1==item[0])[0]
    mask2 = np.where(l2==item[1])[0]
    num_common = len(list(set(mask1).intersection(mask2)))
    num_connections[(item[0],item[1]+nclusters_1)] = num_common

G = nx.Graph()
node_sizes = {}
node_colors = {}
for k,v in num_connections.items():
    # the number of points in the two clusters 
    s1,s2 = cluster_one[2][k[0]],cluster_two[2][k[1]-nclusters_1]
    G.add_node(k[0],pos=cluster_one[0][k[0]])
    G.add_node(k[1],pos=cluster_two[0][k[1]-nclusters_1])
    G.add_edge(k[0],k[1],color='k',weight=v/3)
    node_sizes[k[0]] = s1;node_sizes[k[1]] = s2
    node_colors[k[0]] = 'k';node_colors[k[1]] = 'k'

edges = G.edges()
d = dict(G.degree)
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
nx.draw(G,pos,edges=edges,
        node_color=[node_colors[v] for v in d.keys()],
        nodelist=d.keys(),
        width=weights,
        node_size=[node_sizes[v]*20 for v in d.keys()])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have been clearer. While the two sets of xy points are random in my question, they are related in my actual dataset. They explain to start and end point of each vector. So each quiver displays the starting xy point and the finish xy point. I then find the cluster of these points and then determine the network. I'll plug your answer in now.

Comment: Thanks @meTchaikovsky, I've included some figures of my actual data, instead of random data. The vectors are heavily concentrated around the outside of the circle. They also rarely extend over the entire circle. I'm not sure how I'm getting that output

Comment: @jonboy You're welcome, I forgot to use the actual positions of the data points, that's why the plot looks weird ... Check out my updated post :)

Comment: Thanks. this looks good. Just so I'm clear, it's currently plotting 10 clusters for each set of xy points and there's no adjacency matrix to determine the actual count of vectors between cluster centroids?

Comment: @jonboy You're welcome. There are actually 20 clusters for each set of xy points, as I set both `nclusters_1` and `nclusters_2` to 20. The `dict` `num_connections` contains the information about node connections, i.e., adjacency matrix, check out my updated post, I provided a way to construct adjacency matrix from `num_connections`.